# If statement problem: ignoring other statements even if its true(?)

Tags: c#, if-statement

Even if the user input *matches* the string operations, the statement *always* results to a `false` which in turn *shows the error prompt*.

pardon my code if it seems mediocre, I just started to learn programming for not less than a week. I believe my problem is too specific that's why I'm having a hard time finding a solution. Any will be appreciated.

```
Console.Write("What Operation?: ");

string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input == "+")
{
   op = input;
}
if (input == "-")
{
   op = input;
}
if (input == "*")
{
   op = input;
}
if (input == "/")
{
   op = input;
}
else
{
   op = "Enter a valid operation!!!";
   Console.WriteLine(op);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

if the user writes the correct operation: it should store it to "op" then will be used for the equation.

Comment: The 'else' block here is only related to the last 'if' block (input == '/') so any input that is not '/' will go to this else block

Comment: you are trying to write `else if` but you are missing the `else` part. In your specific use case I would consider `switch(input)`, it is less likely to make that mistake.

Comment: you're absolutely correct. I might have been dizzy to imagine that I'm already using "else if". Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *loop*: keep asking when `input` is not within `validInputs`:

```
  // Let's organize all valid input as a collection for better
  // readability and better maintenance
  HashSet<string> validInputs = new HashSet<string>() {
    "+", "-", "*", "/",
  };

  // Keep asking...
  while (true) {
    // $"...{string.Join(...)}..." let's be nice and let user know 
    // which operations are supported: "+, -, *, /"
    Console.Write($"What Operation? ({string.Join(", ", validInputs)}): "); 

    // Trim() - let's be nice and tolerate leading / trailing spaces
    string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); 

    // ... until user provides a valid input (i.e. which is in validInputs)
    if (validInputs.Contains(input)) {        
      op = input;

      break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid operation!!!"); 
  }
```

Comment: "let the user know which operations are supported"... I can only say [Klingon programming](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~susan/joke/klingon.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The `else` block relates to the previous `if` statement, so you have:

```
if (input == "/")
{
    op = input;
}
else
{
    op = "Enter a valid operation!!!";
    Console.WriteLine(op);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which will mean the `else` block will execute every time the input is not equal to `"/"`.

Instead of using lots of `if` statements you can use a `switch` statement:

```
Console.Write("What Operation?: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string op;
switch (input)
{  
    case "+":
        op = input;
        break;
    case "-":
        op = input;
        break;
    case "*":
        op = input;
        break;
    case "/":
        op = input;
        break;
    default:
        op = "Enter a valid operation!!!";
        Console.WriteLine(op);
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The else in your case is an else for the if condition above it. So whenever the input is not "/" your else will fire.

To fix that you can change your 2nd to 4th if to "else if".

Answer (score 1):

The 'else' block here is only related to the last 'if' block (input == '/') so any input that is not '/' will go to this else block.

What I believe you wanted to do is to perform the last check *when* all other checks failed. For that you'd need an 'else if':

```
    if (input == "+")
    {
        op = input;
    } else if (input == "-")
    {
        op = input;
    } else if (input == "*")
    {
        op = input;
    } else if (input == "/")
    {
        op = input;
    }
    else
    {
        op = "Enter a valid operation!!!";
        Console.WriteLine(op);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

However a better way (more readable) would be to use `switch`